# Is there a way to do a sum of columns in an Excel pivot table with a calculated field greyed out? (It contains distincts values fields)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a pivot table with distincts value. Short story it was needed for manual adjustment of quantity and also I have no access to Power Pivot.

Is there a way to sum columns inside the pivot table? I have to sort and filter by supplier and adding column with formula outside of the pivot table would not make it all follow when filter or sort.

Please see below image

Thanks!

[image: Exemple of pivot table]

Comment: Using Excel 2016

Comment: Is that an OLAP table?

Comment: No this is not an OLAP table. This is an Pivot table from an ODBC table and 1 table with manual entries to make the adjustment. The adjustment column is from the table with manual entries. The table with manual adjustment contains more than 1 line of adjusment for the same product and I had to make it with distincs values that's why I cannot add calculated fields in the pivot table. I would like to be able to sum the month and adjustment month column inside the pivot table because outside it would make issues when filtering or sorting. Filter outside the pivot table is treated independantly...

Comment: Have you tried loading the pivot into Power Query, unpivoting and then continuing with what you're trying to accomplish?  Aside from that, you'd have to write a cube formula for your calculation.